# How do i setup the Kong Ingress Controller (KiC) to work like nginx Ingress with auth-url and auth-signin annotations

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, kong, kong-ingress

In our kubernetes-setup we are using the [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy) in front of a kubernetes-dashboard to provide oidc authentication for the dashboard. A [nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) handles the authorization against the auth2-proxy. We are using some annotations of the nginx ingress to configure nginx that way.

The Problem is, we are currently migrating from nginx to the [Kong Ingress Controller](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller). I can't find a solution to make this work with kong. Does anyone know a solution to achieve this with kong?

We can't use the kong oidc plugin because it's only available with a kong plus or enterprise subscription.

### Our current setup with nginx ingress

We are using the following annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  auth_request_set $token $upstream_http_authorization;
  proxy_set_header Authorization $token;
  proxy_pass_header Authorization;
```

For each incoming request nginx calls `/oauth2/auth` to receive the users token (in a header of the response) before calling the upstream service with the token in the authorization header.
If `/oauth2/auth` does return a 4xx status code it will redirect the user to `/oauth2/start` where the user needs to login.

The oauth2-proxy identifies the user by an cookie (to map him to his token), set after logging in with `/oauth2/start`.